# Looking for a more efficient way of writing some basic if else jQuery script

Tags: jquery, performance

I feel like my script is really redundant and could be written allot more efficiently. If anyone has a better way of doing this please share.

Basically i am showing and hiding a div depending on what radio button is selected using if else statements.

Here is the JQuery

```
//SUMMARY REVIEW DROPDOWN MODULES(FILTER-DROPDOWN)
$(function () {
   //Values of checked radio buttons
  var cd_empty = $('input[id=m4]');
  var adr_empty = $('input[id=m2]');
  var ocpy_empty = $('input[id=m1]');
  var revpar_empty = $('input[id=m3]');
  var cd_checked = $('input[id=m4]:checked', '.ddm-inputs').val();
  var adr_checked = $('input[id=m2]:checked', '.ddm-inputs').val();
  var ocpy_checked = $('input[id=m1]:checked', '.ddm-inputs').val();
  var revpar_checked = $('input[id=m3]:checked', '.ddm-inputs').val();
  var module2 = $('.dd-module-2');

   if(cd_checked === 'on') {
    module2.fadeIn();
   }
  // else {
  //   module2.fadeOut();
  // }

  $(cd_empty).click(
    function(e){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        if(module2.css('display') === 'block') {
          // module2.slideUp();
          // alert('its already open');
          preventDefault(e);
        }
        else {
          module2.slideToggle();
        }
      }

  }); 

  $(adr_empty).click(
    function(e){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        if(module2.css('display') === 'block') {
          // module2.slideUp();
          // alert('its open');
          module2.slideToggle();
        }
        else {
          // alert('its not open');
          module2.hide();
        }
      }
  }); 

  $(revpar_empty).click(
    function(e){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        if(module2.css('display') === 'block') {
          // module2.slideUp();
          // alert('its open');
          module2.slideToggle();
        }
        else {
          // alert('its not open');
          module2.hide();
        }
      }
  }); 

  $(ocpy_empty).click(
    function(e){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        if(module2.css('display') === 'block') {
          // module2.slideUp();
          // alert('its open');
          module2.slideToggle();
        }
        else {
          // alert('its not open');
          module2.hide();
        }
      }
  });
```

});

Comment: I realize i dont need all my variables.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: When you assign your variables they're already jQuery objects, you don't need to re-wrap them with jQuery. Also, *show HTML*; jQuery on its own is more or less useless since we can't *guess* at 'better' techniques.

Comment: Why the attribute equals selectors rather than id selectors? Why not use classes instead since there are multiple of them?

Answer (score 0):

for a start, these functions do the exact same thing:

```
$(adr_empty).click(
    function(e){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        if(module2.css('display') === 'block') {
          // module2.slideUp();
          // alert('its open');
          module2.slideToggle();
        }
        else {
          // alert('its not open');
          module2.hide();
        }
      }
  }); 

  $(revpar_empty).click(
    function(e){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        if(module2.css('display') === 'block') {
          // module2.slideUp();
          // alert('its open');
          module2.slideToggle();
        }
        else {
          // alert('its not open');
          module2.hide();
        }
      }
  }); 

  $(ocpy_empty).click(
    function(e){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        if(module2.css('display') === 'block') {
          // module2.slideUp();
          // alert('its open');
          module2.slideToggle();
        }
        else {
          // alert('its not open');
          module2.hide();
        }
      }
  });
```

You can change them into the same function, as well as taking out the var selectors. So, replace with this:

```
$('input#m1, input#m2, input#m3').click(
    function(e){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        if(module2.css('display') === 'block') {
          // module2.slideUp();
          // alert('its open');
          module2.slideToggle();
        }
        else {
          // alert('its not open');
          module2.hide();
        }
      }
  });
```

Already you can see your code starting to get cleaner... this should give you a good start to re-factoring.

Comment: to add to this, you can also, use the `starts with selector` `$('input[id^="m"]')` making your code event shorter :)

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work in this scenario, as there's an "m4" which doesn't follow the same pattern. Nice idea, though :)